# RESTful service in Java / Tomcat multithread (?) problems

Tags: java, multithreading, rest, tomcat

My RESTful service written in Java consumes a large number of small files (around 300bytes), writes them to disk, inserts them as BLOB into an Oracle database and finally deletes them.
To prevent missing files due to network outage or something I have to write them to disk to bulk insert if there is more than one file on the disk.

My problem is: if I run sequential POST requests via `cURL` and Windows-batch, everything works as expected for an unlimited time, for around 3-5 files per second.

If I create another batch to benchmark the server / service, some files are doubly inserted into the database.

It works like this: `POST request (octet-stream) -> RESTful service [ -> checks for valid file -> writes to disk -> directoryscanner reads all *.XYZ files in directory into String-array -> insert into DB -> if insert OK: delete file].`

I believe due to the multithreaded nature of my service, if in some timespan (say: few miliseconds) two requests are processed, the insert procedure of both threads insert the same file into the DB, one thread deletes them, the first thread can't find the file anymore (because thread2 deleted it already), etc.

My question is: how can I prevent that from happening? I started to create all variables etc. as private so the other thread can't access them (I do believe that's how it works). But in the very limited timespan of both (or all) threads coexisting, thread2 "steals" the file from thread1, but *AFTER* thread1 already inserted it.

As you can probably deduce, I'm no professional Java-programmer whatsoever, so maybe you can point me in the right direction. Let me know if you need code snippets or anything.

---

**EDIT**
To clarify the workflow:
The service gets an octet-stream of data via http POST to some URI `/service/{ID}/{file}`, where ID is an integer and file is the extension of the file in the request.
The service writes the file to disk, then inserts the file into the DB (BLOB).
Sometimes the file can be a zip-compressed file, which I have to extract, *then* insert the extracted files into the DB.
In the case of a network outage, I can't get a connection to the DB. That's why I write every single file to disk, read them into a String array and insert them into the DB as soon as the connection is up again.

I think the problem is that, two threads write two files simultaneously, both threads scan the file into their own string array, both threads upload the files. *(<- That's where I think I could be wrong).*  I can reproduce this problem and even up it to 3 or 4 or 5 cURL-batches, then 3 or 4 or 5 files are duplicates.

**EDIT2 (log example)**

> 10-Jun-2016 09:56:14.400 SEVERE [**pool-275-thread-1**] ServiceResource.doSendData array: file1.tst - [Ljava.lang.String;@3107ce05
>
> 10-Jun-2016 09:56:14.400 SEVERE [**pool-274-thread-1**] ServiceResource.doSendData array: file1.tst - [Ljava.lang.String;@6996e2db

Comment: Sounds like you need database constraints so the database ensures you can't insert duplicates (and maybe transactions?). But I don't understand how those files can be duplicates. What are they & how can it be that 2 requests refer to the same file? Can you explain how & what is written to disk & what the directory scanner part is needed (you just wrote(?) those files, why scan them?)

Comment: synchronize the method call, then it won't be able to run twice until it has finished its job 

    public synchronized void yourmethod() {
       // do stuff
    }

Comment: @zapl oh sorry, I forgot to mention that I can't use constraints in the table. I sometimes have to duplicate the name in the DB to repair some files. As for "how & what is written to disk...", I'll try to clarify in my question.

Comment: @david thank you, I'll check your suggestion

Comment: @david I tried the synchronized approach, but the problem persists.

Comment: @zapl I edited my question to clarify + added a log example of a duplicate file

Comment: What you need is synchronization at higher level. When you write a file to disk. Maintain its ID/name/path in some queue like structure. This queue must be a shared structure. It can be declared at Controller or Service Layer. The processors (piece of code which writes file to db) can pick a record from queue, read corresponding file and write it to database. This queue can be a Java Queue.Also I suggest you to eliminate bulk processing with parallel processing

Comment: Generate a unique id for each thread and add it to the file name before wrting to disk. The thread should delete only the files with its own id. You can ignore it when insert into the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I went with recoding the directoryscanner part. Now I receive the file, extract it if it's a zip, get the fileheaders, insert them into the database, and finally delete them if transmitted correctly. If there is no connection to the DB, the files are written to disk and as soon as the DB is online again, inserted into the DB.
Thanks for the input, I really learned some stuff here :)